# get user name and email using powershell script from a document library

Tags: 2010, 2013, powershell, sharepoint-server

1) i want to get the user email and send email ,  who  uploaded  the documents from 8 to 9 PM  using power shell script.
i want distinct users

these users are domain users who uploaded documents.
[image]

Comment: Hi, for example, i want to get the those documents which are uploaded today from 8 to 9 am

Answer (score 2):

Every document has several properties, such as ModifiedBy, Author, etc. You can display them using, e.g.

```
$ctx.Load($document)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
Write-Host $document.Author
```

What you will receive, however, here will look like:
SharePoint.User.User

You will need to load the users separately from the documents, otherwise you will get only the name of the object class.

```
    $ctx.Load($document.Author)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

Here is an example with loading authors of deleted documents:
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Detailed-report-on-all-b2e72bf0

Comment: here how i put modified data condition where i can get documents only from 8 am to 10 am.